# Predicative separation and the limited principle of omniscience

Tags: logic, set-theory, constructive-mathematics

The axiom schema of predicative separation says that, for a set X and a predicate F containing only bounded quantifiers, there exists a set whose members are exactly those members of X which satisfy F. As I understand it, a bounded quantifier is a quantifier of the form (∀x∈X) or (∃x∈X), where X is a set. If I’m interpreting this correctly, then, for a function f from X to Y, where X and Y are both sets, {y∈Y:(∃x∈X)(f(x)=y)} is a set.

Here’s my problem. Let  denote the set {0,1}. Let α:ℕ→ be an arbitrary binary sequence. ℕ is clearly a set, as is , so, by the axiom schema of predicative separation, {x∈:(∃n∈ℕ)(α(n)=x)} or Im(α) is a set, in particular, a subset of . Because  is finite, its power-set P()={∅,{0},{1},} is constructible and finite, so we can exhaustively check which values in P() Im(α) can take. By definition of a function, we know that since ℕ is inhabited, Im(α) is inhabited, so it can’t equal the empty set. Assume that Im(α)={0}; then (∀n∈ℕ)(α(n)=0). Assume that Im(α)={1} or Im(α)=; then (∃n∈ℕ)(α(n)=1). Because α is arbitrary, this implies the limited principle of omniscience, that (∀α:ℕ→)((∀n∈ℕ)(α(n)=0)∨(∃n∈ℕ)(α(n)=1)), which constructive logicians reject.

I'm confident I must have misunderstood something, because it doesn't feel quite right that the axiom schema of predicative separation alone should prove something nonconstructive. I think my logic is fine, so I'm guessing my mistake is in my interpretation of either the axiom schema of predicative separation or bounded quantifiers; or maybe I haven't adequately defined in which system of constructive set theory I've been working. I really don't know, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, constructive mathematics will reject the assertion that $P(\{ 0, 1 \}) = \{ \emptyset, \{ 0 \}, \{ 1 \}, \{ 0, 1 \} \}$, considering this to be essentially a product of two instances of the law of excluded middle.

For a slightly smaller example, let $\phi$ be any predicate with bounded quantifiers and with no free variables.  Then $S := \{ x \in \{ 0 \} \mid \phi \}$ is in $P(\{ 0 \})$.  However, if we assert that $P(\{ 0 \}) = \{ \emptyset, \{ 0 \} \}$, then $S = \emptyset$ is equivalent to $\lnot \phi$, and $S = \{ 0 \}$ is equivalent to $\phi$.  So, in this way, the assertion that $P(\{ 0 \}) = \{ \emptyset, \{ 0 \} \}$ is equivalent to claiming that the law of excluded middle holds on all predicates with bounded quantifiers - at least in the presence of the axiom schema of predicative separation.

That said, we often are interested in when a certain subset of $X$ is decidable, i.e. when membership in that subset is a decidable proposition for each $x \in X$.  In the language of topos theory, for example, with a subobject classifier $\Omega$ representing a set of possible truth values, the full power set of $X$ would correspond to functions $X \to \Omega$ whereas the set of decidable subsets of $X$ would correspond to functions $X \to \{ T, F \}$; and we do not necessarily have $\Omega = \{ T, F \}$.

Comment: While (I think) I understand your explanation as to why P({0,1})={∅,{0},{1},{0,1}} is an instance of excluded middle, I also can't help but feel that P({0,1}) couldn't look any other way.
Let X:={0,...,n} : the principle of explosion guarantees that ∅ is in P(X); obviously, {0} through {n} are in P(X); and there are only finitely many possible unions of singletons in X; so how does that not cover all subsets of X?
Basically, what I'm getting at is, are there systems of constructive logic that allow things like P({0,1})={∅,{0},{1},{0,1}}, but have, say, a different axiom schema of separation?

Comment: The (constructive) problem with your idea about the power set isnt that there are 'additional' elements than the ones you list, per se. The problem is your idea that we are able to "check" which of the elements it is. This is what leads to the LPO in your argument, because you can define subsets of a finite set based on propositions about infinite sets. Such 'sub-finite' sets are members of the power set, even though we _can't_ check which of the four usual elements each one is. If you wanted to avoid this, it seems like you'd have to limit yourself to e.g. _finitely_ bounded separation.

Comment: @ExcessCoke As Daniel Schepler essentially proved, saying $\{x\in\{0\}\mid\varphi\}=\{\varnothing,\{0\}\}$ is essentially equivalent to saying $\varphi$ is decidable. Therefore, allowing separation for anything other than decidable predicates would go beyond constructive logic though not necessarily all the way to classical logic.

Comment: Here's a simple example semantics for a constructive logic that may make things more clear. Imagine that you have a notion of truth such that things can be true or false now and they can be true or false later, but once something becomes true it cannot become false. With this semantics, something is "true" if it *always* true, therefore $\neg\varphi$ is "true" *only* if $\varphi$ is always false. Excluded middle fails because if $\varphi$ goes from false to true then $\varphi\lor\neg\varphi\equiv\varphi\lor\bot\equiv\varphi\not\equiv\top$.

Comment: Saying $P(\{0\})=\{\varnothing,\{0\}\}$ in this context states that elements of $P(\{0\})$ are either always $\varnothing$ or always $\{0\}$. However, $\{x\in\{0\}\mid\varphi\}$ is $\varnothing$ now and $\{0\}$ later. Call that subset $S$. *Externally*, we could say that $P(\{0\})$ has three values. *Internally*, though, $S=\varnothing$ is always false, $S=\{0\}$ is false now and true later, thus $\neg(S=\{0\})$ is also always false. So neither $S=\{0\}$ nor $S\neq\{0\}$ is "true".